# A query to get forum threads/replies - only shows the latest one

Tags: php, mysqli, forum

Good day to you!

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but I just can't get it to work.
I have a forum, which is supposed to display all threads, ordered by the latest reply.
**Database:**
*table threads*
thread_id, category_id, title, created, author, status

*table replies*
reply_id, thread_id, created, text

**Query:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM threads, replies 
WHERE threads.thread_id=replies.thread_id AND threads.category_id=$cat 
AND threads.status=1 ORDER BY replies.reply_id DESC");
```

**Problem:**
It only displays the thread with the latest reply. I use a while loop to echo out all rows. mysqli_num_rows($query) shows 3, yet only one thread is printed. The while loop simply consist of:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $thread_id = $r['thread_id'];
                    $total_comments = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT thread_id FROM replies WHERE thread_id=$thread_id"));
                    $last_comment = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE thread_id=$thread_id ORDER BY reply_id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
                    $rLastComment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_comment);
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT author FROM threads WHERE thread_id=$thread_id");
    $a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo '<tr>
     <td><img src="" alt=""></td>
     <td><a href="/forum/thread/'.$thread_id.'">'.$status.''.(substr($r['title'], 0, 15)).'</a> </td>
     <td>'.$a['author'].'</td>
     <td>'.($total_comments).'</td>
     <td>'.$lastComment.'</td>
     </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` repeatedly, once for each row.

Check the PHP docs for examples on how to use a while loop to output your results: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I'm using while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)), the loop inside is simply to get the author for the thread.